# Create JSON Type in PostgreSQL from Java Entity

Tags: java, json, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

How I can create a field with JSON Type in my PostgreSQL database from JPA or Hibernate annotations?

For example if I want

`character varying(n)` in PostgreSQL I use in my Java Entity

`@Column
 private String name;`

So, I want to have a `json` in PostgreSQL. What is need to add in my Java entity class for that?

Answer (score 0):

There are two excellent articles from two Hibernate experts on that topic:

Vlad Mihalcea, Hibernate commiter and book author:

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-schema-less-eav-entity-attribute-value-data-using-json-and-hibernate/

Thorben Jansen, JPA expert:

https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-postgresqls-jsonb-data-type-hibernate/

Comment: Are these articles only specific to JSONB? Or do they work for json as well?